# How do I mass install apt packages conditionally from a file?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, ppa

#### Goal

I would like to install multiple APT packages using a file.

```bsh
apt_install_from_file "packages" # assumes 'packages' is a readable file in the $PWD
```

**Note**: *I understand that there are other ways of doing this and I am re-inventing the wheel to speak, but I am hoping this way could make others lives easier.*

#### File-Structure

`packages`:

```bsh
# ppa
ppa "deadsnakes/ppa"

# packages
apt "tree"

# deb
deb "fzy" [args: "https://github.com/jhawthorn/fzy/releases/download/0.9/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb", "$HOME", "fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb"]
```

#### Requirements

1. Ignore any line that starts with `#` because that is a comment
2. If the line starts with `ppa` then run the following command with the text enclosed by the quotes.
   e.g. `ppa "deadsnakes/ppa"` => 
   `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa &> /dev/null`
3. If the line starts with `apt` then run the following command with the text enclosed by the quotes.
   e.g. `apt "tree"` => `sudo apt install --allow-unauthenticated -qqy tree`
4. If the line starts with `deb` then grab the text enclosed by quotes as well as grab the text that follows `args` enclosed by quotes.

#### Current Function:

```bsh
apt_install_from_file() {

    declare -r FILE_PATH="$1"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Install package(s)

    if [ -e "$FILE_PATH" ]; then

        cat < "$FILE_PATH" | while read -r LINE; do
            if [[ "$LINE" == *"#"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                continue
            elif [[ "$LINE" == *"ppa"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                # ppa= Grab text enclosed by quotes following "ppa"
                sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:"$ppa" &> /dev/null \
                   && sudo apt update
            elif [[ "$LINE" == *"apt"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                package="$LINE" # Grab text enclosed by quotes following "apt"
                sudo apt install --allow-unauthenticated -qqy "$package"
            elif [[ "$LINE" == *"deb"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                #package_name= Grab text enclosed by quotes following "deb"
                #url= Grab text enclosed by quotes following "args"
                #target_path= Grab text enclosed by quotes following "args"
                #file_name= Grab text enclosed by quotes following "args"
                #file_path="$target_path" + "/" + "$file_name"  

                wget $url -O $file_path && \
                   sudo dpkg -i $file_path && sudo apt-get install -f && \
                   sudo rm -rf $file_path && sudo apt autoremove -qqy
            fi
        done

    fi

}
```

#### Problem

I need help filling in the blanks to the function given my requirement list.

Comment: It would be much faster to fill an array and call `apt` etc. just once on it. Instead of using `sudo` in the script, run the whole thing as root. You can install `.deb` files with `apt -i` in one go, no need to resolve depency problems this way.

Comment: Is your input file's structure carved in stone or can you change it?

Comment: @PerlDuck If there is a better more organized way to do this, then I am open to it.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou for starters, it would be a lot simpler if you nuked most of those quotes, and changed the array into simple space-separated words.

Comment: @muru What exactly do you mean? Instead of `[args: "", "" ...]` you mean `[args: word1 word2 ...]`

Comment: @NicholasAdamou I mean `deb fzy https://github.com/jhawthorn/fzy/releases/download/0.9/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb $HOME fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar being used here isn't doing shell scripting any favours, but it will be slightly easier to parse that file if you use regular expressions. Bash's regular expression comparison saves groups `(...)` in the `BASH_REMATCH` array, so you can, in one go, test for a valid line and parse it. For example:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
declare -A regex
regex["comment"]='^#(.*)'
regex["ppa"]='ppa "(.*)"'
regex["apt"]='apt "(.*)"'
regex["deb"]='deb "(.*)" \[args: "(.*)", "(.*)", "(.*)"\]'
while read LINE
do
    if [[ $LINE =~ ${regex[comment]} ]]
    then
        printf "Comment: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        continue
    elif [[ $LINE =~ ${regex[ppa]} ]]
    then
        ppa=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        printf "PPA: %s\n" "$ppa"
    elif [[ $LINE =~ ${regex[apt]} ]]
    then
        package=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        printf "APT: %s\n" "$package"
    elif [[ $LINE =~ ${regex[deb]} ]]
    then
        package_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        url=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        target_path=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        file_name=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
        file_path="$target_path/$file_name"

        printf "package_name: %s\n" "$package_name"
        printf "url: %s\n" "$url"
        printf "file_path: %s\n" "$file_path"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

With your example file:

```
$ ./foo.sh foo.txt
Comment:  ppa
PPA: deadsnakes/ppa
Comment:  packages
APT: tree
Comment:  deb
package_name: fzy
url: https://github.com/jhawthorn/fzy/releases/download/0.9/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb
file_path: $HOME/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

**There's already a format** for controlling apt using a file. It's an ordinary shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Instructions: Run me using sudo: $ sudo install_script.sh
# WARNING: All errors have been muted or thrown out. Guess I don't want to know...

# PPA
add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa &> /dev/null
add-apt-repository -y ppa:font-manager/staging &> /dev/null
add-apt-repository -y ppa:fish-shell/release-2 &> /dev/null
add-apt-repository -y ppa:zanchey/asciinema &> /dev/null

# packages
apt install --allow-unauthenticated -qqy tree symlinks

# deb
wget https://github.com/jhawthorn/fzy/releases/download/0.9/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb -O /tmp/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb
apt --install /tmp/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb -qqy
rm /tmp/fzy_0.9-1_amd64.deb
```

There are lots of ways to make a script more complex and fun to play with.

There are also lots of ways to clean up a script and make it more readable and maintainable for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. However, this does not answer my question.

Comment: Future readers will benefit from knowing the standard, as well as your variation upon that standard.

Comment: I like it. Totally to the point so it looks clean and is easy to understand.  I spent years making my own scripts in the past and this would have saved me a lot of time ;)  so +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Background:

After a bit of research and trial and error, I figured out I could use the tool `cut` in conjunction with `echo`.

#### Example:

To achieve the desired output take the following example.

`packages`:

```bsh
# packages
apt "tree"
```

`test.sh`:

```bsh
apt_install_from_file() {

    declare -r FILE_PATH="$1"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Install package(s)

    if [ -e "$FILE_PATH" ]; then

        cat < "$FILE_PATH" | while read -r LINE; do

            if [[ "$LINE" == *"#"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                continue
            elif [[ "$LINE" == *"apt"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                package="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f2)"
                echo "$package"
            fi

        done
    fi

}
```

**Usage**:

`./test.sh packages`

#### Breakdown:

Given the line `package="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f2)"`, lets break it down.

1. First, we `echo` the contents of the line.
2. Then, we pip that result to `cut` which splits the contents of `$LINE` into multiple fields based on a given delimiter. The delimiter in our case is `"`. We had to place a `\` in front of the `"` because the quote character must be escaped.
3. Next, we then grab the second field of that split, which contains `tree`.
4. Finally, we store the contents of what `$()` returns into `package` of which case is `tree` (e.g. `$()` => `tree`).

#### Modified Function:

```bsh
apt_install_from_file() {

    declare -r FILE_PATH="$1"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Install package(s)

    if [ -e "$FILE_PATH" ]; then

        cat < "$FILE_PATH" | while read -r LINE; do
            if [[ "$LINE" == *"#"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                continue
            elif [[ "$LINE" == *"ppa"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                ppa="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f2)"
                sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:"$ppa" &> /dev/null \
                   && sudo apt update
            elif [[ "$LINE" == *"apt"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                package="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f2)"
                sudo apt install --allow-unauthenticated -qqy "$package"
            elif [[ "$LINE" == *"deb"* || -z "$LINE" ]]; then
                package_name="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f2)"
                url="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f4)"
                target_path="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f6)"
                file_name="$(echo $LINE | cut -d \" -f8)"
                file_path="$target_path/$file_name"  

                wget $url -O $file_path && \
                   sudo dpkg -i $file_path && sudo apt-get install -f && \
                   sudo rm -rf $file_path && sudo apt autoremove -qqy
            fi
        done

    fi

}
```

#### Conclusion:

This may not be the best solution to my problem I listed above and that it is indeed a hacky solution, so if there is a better one, please do not hesitate to write an updated answer!